# Return context from class based view in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

So if I used function views like so :

```
def messageView(request):
    webpages_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
    date_dict = {'access_records':webpages_list}
    return render(request,'index.html',context=date_dict)
```

And my url resolver looks like this : `path('', views.messageView , name='index'),`

Every thing is fine, my records are displayed as expected :
[image]

HOWEVER, when I try to use class based view like so :

```
class IndexView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm 
    template_name = "index.html"

    def index(self,request):
        webpages_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
        date_dict = {'access_records':webpages_list}

        return render(request, self.template_name,context=date_dict )
```

And url is like so : `path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),`

I get nothing in this case, I've tried looking for simple cases of just returning a context from a class view in django online, but to no avail.

What exactly am I misunderstanding here please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method.

Put this in your class based view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['access_records'] = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
    return context
```

It returns a dictionary representing the template context.

Comment: Thank you , this works. Am I to do something like this every single time I want to use class views in such a way ?

Or is it possible that there is a simpler in built function by django that I am missing for this ?

Comment: When you use class based views you should override ```get_context_data``` method in order to populate a dictionary that will be used as the template context. I provided you the link to the documentation in my answer for more details. There are other approaches as well like overriding the ```get``` method and build the context dict there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just learning CBVs, start with a simple `View` instead of `CreateView`. This is the easiest way to migrate from FBVs to CBVs:

```
from django.views import View

class IndexView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        webpages_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
        date_dict = {'access_records': webpages_list}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=date_dict)

    def post(self, request):
        raise NotImplementedError
```